# Understanding of countable set short theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling to understand what the theorem is stating. 
[image]

**Question 1**

Let n equals 2, would that mean that $B_n$ would be $B_2$= $\left\{\left\{a_1\right\},\left\{a_1,a_2\right\}\right\}$?

**Question 2**

Given n=2 and 3 how would small b, be described?

In the case of $B_{n-1}$,would the sets (b,a), be

(0,$a_1$),($b_1$,$a_2$).

I have a feeling I am totally lost and I am hoping someone could provide a descret example so that I understand what it is stating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer for Question 1

Let A = {a,b,c} then B_2 = {(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c)}

That's way the proof says B_1 = A

Comment: What about when $b_(n-1)$

Comment: You mean B_(n-1) ?

Comment: B_(n-1) is a set. Every element in that set has form (a_1,a_2,...,a_(n-1)). 

B_n is a set. Every element in that set has form (a_1, a_2,...,a_n)). 

That's why you can write the element of B_n with ( b, a_n) where b = (a_1,a_2,....,a(n-1))

Comment: Note that $(b,a)$ is not a set. It's an element of set $B_n$

Comment: $B_{n-1}$ is a set. Every element in that set has form $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1})$. $B_n$ is a set. Every element in that set has form $(a_1, a_2,...,a_n))$. That's why you can write the element of $B_n$ with $(b, a_n)$ where $b=(a_1,a_2,....,a_{n-1})$

Comment: Yeah, finally i can write those math texts beautifully !

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: If $n=2$ then $B$ is of the form $B_2 = \{ (a_i , a_j) : a_i , a_j \in A\}$.

Question 2: n - 1 = 2 , n = 3

$ \{ (b , a) : b \in B_2  , a \in A \}$ It is like $( (a_i , a_j ) , a_k) $ and $a_i , a_j , a_k \in A$.